# How to install SSAS in SQL server 2019

Tags: ssas

I installed SQL Server 2019 and Analysis Services.

Now I need to install SSDT to create Analysis Services projects.

I did some research and saw that to create the SSAS projects it is necessary to install Visual Studio 2019 first, as there is no separate installation of SSDT, as it was before, is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes now it works in this way.

[Install SSDT with Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2019)